# CSS hover image link not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, hyperlink, hover

Please refer http://solarisdutamas.com/fb/KonzeptGarden/sample.php, mouse over to "Pebbles Wash" and click the image. It working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the link not working in IE.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Konzept Garden</title>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#main {
width: 520px;
height: 228px;
background-image: url(stone.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;}

#main ul li {
list-style: none;
display: inline;}

#main ul li:hover {
visibility: visible;}

#main ul li a {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;}

#main ul li a:hover {
z-index: 100;}

#main ul li img {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
right: 999em;}

#submain1 .butt1 a {
left: 8px;
top: 80px;
    width: 90px;
height: 32px;}

#main ul .butt1:hover img {
    left: 8px;
    top: 80px;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; width: 520px;">
<div id="main">
<ul id="submain1">
<li class="butt1"><a href="http://konzeptstone.com/p_pebbles.html" target="_blank"></a><img src="p1.png"></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using earlier versions of IE, it has issues with `:hover`.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an overkill but this will ensure it works even on I.E. 6:

```
#submain1 .butt1 a:link, a:active, a:visited {
   left: 8px;
   top: 80px;
   width: 90px;
   height: 32px;
   display:block;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

then:

```
<li class="butt1"><a href="http://konzeptstone.com/p_pebbles.html" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a><img src="p1.png"></li>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use jQuery if you have it installed. Like Jason said, :hover doesn't work in IE6 and below, for anything OTHER than anchors.

Assuming you can use jQuery, the solution would be:

```
$('#main ul li').hover(function(){
  $(this).show();
});
```

Another option using jQuery would be adding a class dynamically on Hover.

```
$('#main ul li').hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass('hoverState');
});
```

And then the CSS would be:

```
#main ul li.hoverState {
visibility: visible;}
```